# Uploading only changed files to web host

Tags: msbuild

Using msbuild, how can I upload only changed files to my web host (from an asp.net web application)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [msbuildtasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) and [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) (or using exec).

Answer (score 1):

I would use [MSDeploy](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/) for this. Many third party hosts are starting to support MSDeploy as well.